# Ajax запрос и в ответе забрать знаение сессии

Tags: php

мастера). Такая проблема. Есть аякс запрос на сервер:

```
function ataka(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '../request/start.php?ataka',
            success: function(data){
                document.getElementById('hp').textContent = data;
            }
        });
    }
```

Сам код на сервере:

```
    if(isset($_GET['ataka'])){
    $ataka = rand(5,10);
    $mob_ataka = rand(1,5);
    $_SESSION['mob_hp'] = $_SESSION['mob_hp'] - $ataka;
    $_SESSION['user_hp'] = $_SESSION['user_hp'] - $mob_ataka;
    echo $_SESSION['mob_hp'];
    echo $ataka;
    }
```

В ответ я получаю сразу два значения в одной переменной. Как разделить? Что бы $_SESSION['mob_hp']; улетело в один блок, а  $ataka; в другой блок?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- у `ajax` поставить ожидание типа ответа `json`, то есть добавить `dataType: 'json'`
- в ответе на сервере слать `json`, то есть

  ```
  echo json_encode(['mob_hp' => 111, 'user_hp' => 222]);
  exit();
  ```
- и в получении данных писать уже:

  ```
  document.getElementById('hp').textContent = data.user_hp;
  document.getElementById('smthElse').textContent = data.mob_hp;
  ```

Comment: Сейчас попробую. Спасибо.